# Chrome and Firefox are both lagging even after a reboot

Tags: graphics, firefox, google-chrome, intel-graphics

I've been playing gobattle and slither for months. Last night they both started lagging very badly. A restart usually takes care of it and things are back to normal but last night, I got a warning that the graphics weren't configured properly and it asked me to configure them while booting. I chose to use the defaults and boot the system. It did that to me twice. Now the graphics in gobattle and slither are lagging horribly. When I do something, it takes forever for my character to do it onscreen. How do I fix this?

Comment: what were the recent changes you made like an update or an new installation ?

Comment: Just the ytdownloader that I can remember. I install my updates and don't pay much attention to them.

Comment: It must be due to the update to the graphics card driver...